# Sending file using WebCLient: What is userToken?

Tags: c#, webclient

I've been trying to upload file to server over `WebClient` in a SileverLight app. I've come across this `OpenWriteAsync` method and the first two arguments it gets are clear but the third is of type object and it's name is `UserToken` so although I made a lot of search I couldn't find a clear description on what it is and how it should be used. (UserToken parameter). So what goes in there?

**A user-defined object that is....** that Microsoft has provided is an awful explanation. I mean they had to provide a map of all the properties that can go in there like :

```
new {param1 = value, param2= value}
```

Theres no way a developer can guess how the user-defined object works naturally.

Comment: Did you try to search for the documentation? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144219(v=vs.110).aspx. Is the documentation not clear? "A user-defined object that is passed to the method invoked when the asynchronous operation completes". What part is not clear?

Comment: @VikasGupta: did you even read the content of the link you attached. WHere's the description then ? And I wanna know what goes in there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically it's whatever you want it to be. It contains state data that will be passed to the event args in the `OpenWriteCompleted` event. The `WebClient` doesn't use this data in any way other than passing it on.

```
private void OpenWrite()
{
    webClient.OpenWriteCompleted += webClient_OpenWriteCompleted;

    // I'm just using this as an example. It can be any data type, but I am using byte[] so I can write it to the stream later.
    byte[] data = new byte[] { 0, 1, 3, 4 }; 

    webClient.OpenWriteAsync(uri, method, data);
}

private void webClient_OpenWriteCompleted(object sender, OpenWriteCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Now e.UserState contains whatever data you passed as the userToken.
    byte[] data = (byte[])e.UserState;

    // Now write this data to the stream
    e.Result.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    e.Result.Close();
}
```

If you don't need to pass any state information, just pass `null`.

Comment: It's openWrite, then where should the Byte array I wanna write to somewhere go?

Comment: `e.Result` contains a writable stream. Write your byte array to that sream.

Comment: You mean I write the stream to the result or in an other word the Response of the Async task? It doesn't make any sense

Comment: Yes, you write to the result of the stream. The async task is just to open the stream. (You can't write to the stream before it is open.)

Comment: The Async result is a returned response, do you know what you are talking about it returns Task<T> !!!

Comment: @JAX Where does the `Task<T>` come from?

Comment: What OpenWriteAsync overload are you looking at? I am looking at this one, which returns void: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144219(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @nick_w: what is the point of an Async? being void? (The can be void but not in this context)

Comment: If you want a `Task<Stream>`, use `OpenWriteTaskAsync`, which has no `userToken`.

Comment: @aj_r: It's silverlight!!

Comment: @JAX Does it matter that the method does not return an awaitable task?

Comment: @aj_r: And you don't understand me, it's pointless to write to the result of a returned something. e,Result is already returned it posts nothing back to the server.

Comment: Right, of course. In that case, I guess you don't get `OpenWriteTaskAsync`. Still, `OpenWriteAsync` returns void: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144219(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: @nick_w: This is not the matter of what it returns, the UserToken as far as I can guess is an object which responsible for the the stream, it gets the input and the file name, etc, I just don't know how to use it!

Comment: @JAX There is an example of how to write to the steam here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.openwritecompletedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @JAX: Sure its does. Try it :). I also forgot to call `Close()` before; I've added it now.

Comment: @nick_w: This is not what I'm looking for. For example in MVC html helpers we have something similar, you can't just pass in anything, the properties must either follow naming rules or match the parameter names in the actionresult method. like `new {@Class= "", @Style =""}`. this object works the same way, I've seen people passing Byte[] in there, how it works is what I wanna know. Like a complete documentation or guide.

Comment: @JAX If you want to pass in a `byte[]` array then do that. You would then cast it back to a `byte[]` array in the `OpenWriteCompleted` handler just like in aj_r's answer.

Comment: @JAX: The userToken is different from MVC html helpers in that you CAN pass whatever you want in there. There's nothing more to document. You're not going to get anything better than the link nick_w posted above.

Comment: @nick_w: There's more than that, the file name can also go in there, ok what else can be in there ? and how does it work. This is the question?

Comment: @aj_r: If anything goes in there, then what's the point of it, how the method recognize them and how does it use them ? Let's say reflection, still it can't understand what they are.

Comment: @JAX File name? You can pass anything you like in there. If you have multiple things to pass in, create your own object, call it `MyState` or whatever, and pass that in.

Comment: @JAX: did you read my answer? The point of the `userToken` is to pass whatever data you want to the `OpenWriteCompleted` handler so you can access it there.

Comment: @aj_r: The event you are using is `OpenWriteCompletedEventArgs e` means it fires when OpenWrite is Completed. So when it is completed do you expect it to upload file on the server? if it does so, then I think microsoft developers where out of their minds when they named it

Comment: @aj_r: and access the object where? in the event? for what purpose? I mean why do I ever have to do that?

Comment: @JAX: Yes - what they mean by "OpenWriteCompleted" is "the stream has finished opening". I believe the stream is some form of `NetworkStream` behind the scenes, so any data you write to it gets sent to the server.

Comment: @JAX: Yes, to access the object in the `OpenWriteCompleted` event. Depending on how you are doing things, you might not need it at all. If you don't need it, just pass `null` as the `userToken`.

Comment: @aj_r: I never use something that is badly designed, this is (if you are right) a good example. Will create my own uploader!

Comment: @JAX Why do you say this is badly designed? It seems very simple to me. It is very common to pass state around when using asynchronous code. The API exposed here is more like the old style of doing threaded code than the newer async/await pattern.

Comment: @aj_r: No, this is ambiguous, imagine the next developer just comes across that and he is blurred about it like me then it causes complications, I just designed a WCF service, I send the byte array array to the server and do the upload in there. You know, SIlverLight is very limited so that's the most efficient way so I can partition the byte array for sending large files.